# How to copy a partial or skeleton h5py file

Tags: python, h5py

I have a few questions wrapped up into this issue. I realize this might be a convoluted post and can provide extra details.

A code package I use can produce large .h5 files (source.h5) (100+ Gb), where almost all of this data resides in 1 dataset (group2/D). I want to make a new .h5 file (dest.h5) using Python that contains all datasets except group2/D of source.h5 without needing to copy the entire file. I then will condense group2/D after some postprocessing and write a new group2/D in dest.h5 with much less data. However, I need to keep source.h5 because this postprocessing may need to be performed multiple times into multiple destination files.

source.h5 is always structured the same and cannot be changed in either source.h5 or dest.h5, where each letter is a dataset:

```
group1/A
group1/B
group2/C
group2/D
```

I thus want to initially make a file with this format:

```
group1/A
group1/B
group2/C
```

and again, fill in group2/D later. Simply copying source.h5 multiple times is always possible, but I'd like to avoid having to copy a huge file a bunch of times because disk space is limited and this is something that isn't a 1 off case.

I searched and found this question ([How to partially copy using python an Hdf5 file into a new one keeping the same structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510240/how-to-partially-copy-using-python-an-hdf5-file-into-a-new-one-keeping-the-same)) and tested if dest.h5 would be the same as source.h5:

```
fs = h5py.File('source.h5', 'r')
fd = h5py.File('dest.h5', 'w')
fs.copy('group1', fd)
fd.create_group('group2')
fs.copy('group2/C', fd['/group2'])
fd.copy('group2/D', fd['/group2'])
fs.close()
fd.close()
```

but the code package I used couldn't read the file I created (which I must have happen), implying there was some critical data loss when I did this operation (the file sizes differ by 7 kb also). I'm assuming the problem was when I created group2 manually because I checked with numpy that the values in group1 datasets exactly matched in both source.h5 and dest.h5. Before I did any digging into what data is missing I wanted to get a few things out of the way:

**Question 1:** Is there .h5 file metadata that accompanies each group or dataset? If so, how can I see it so I can create a group2 in dest.h5 that exactly matches the one in source.h5? Is there a way to see if 2 groups (not datasets) exactly match each other?

**Question 2:** Alternatively, is it possible to simply copy the data structure of a .h5 file (i.e. groups and datasets with empty lists as a skeleton file) so that fields can be populated later? Or, as a subset of this question, is there a way to copy a blank dataset to another file such that any metadata is retained (assuming there is some)?

**Question 3:** Finally, to avoid all this, is it possible to just copy a subset of source.h5 to dest.h5? With something like:

```
fs.copy(['group1','group2/C'], fd)
```

Thanks for your time. I appreciate you reading this far

Comment: When I do something similar on one of my files, and compare results with `h5dump`, the difference between the two copy methods is that `group1` is copied with attributes.  `group2` attributes are not copied.

Comment: If I understand, I think you have a typo in `fd.copy('group2/D', fd['/group2'])` -- don't you want `fs.copy()`? If that doesn't solve the problem, there are there things to consider. The attributes @hjpaul mentioned are what you call metadata. You can retrieve the attributes and add to the new groups/datasets in `fd`. SO Topic **54020109** shows how to do that. Is it possible the downstream code package has a dependency between `group2/D` and data in another group? When debugging these problems, I recommend **HDFViewer** (from HDF Group) to see the data and attributes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020109/filter-hdf-dataset-from-h5-file-using-attribute